# Firefinder doesn't find element but Firebug or Selenium IDE do

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-ide

I have a problem with finding web elements in my web application.
When I use Selenium IDE everything is ok, the element can be found. In Firebug or Chrome developer tools  is ok as well (element is found by xpath).
But when I use the same xpath expression in FirePath or FireFinder or WebDriver script (java) there are any element found.
This is html code of example element:

```
<input id="btnWyloguj" class="Button80" type="submit" name="btnWyloguj" value="Wyloguj" style="background-color: rgb(212, 208, 200);">
```

and this is my xpath:
`//input[@id='btnWyloguj']`
I tried css selectors as well and result is the same.
Has anyone had similiar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. 
As it turns out, elements I wanted to find was inside iframe tags. Iframe is like second inner document, but xpath can work only on 1 document. I used `driver.switchTo().frame("frameId");` command and my webdriver script is working now.